# Error Code: 1060 when creating view

Tags: mysql, create-view

I'm trying to create a view but I get duplicate column name 'id' error. It works on it's own but as soon as i create a view it doesn't work.

`create view question1_responders as
 select * from survey_responders
    join survey_responses
    on survey_responses.survey_responder_id = survey_responders.id
    where survey_question_id = 1
    order by survey_responders.id`

Comment: Whats the complete error message?Maybe you have ambiguous column name so you need to specify the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `CREATE VIEW` statement to be like below by qualifying each column name. The error is mostly because of the `select *` part. Either specify specific columns you want to fetch (OR) specify `table_name.*`

```
create view question1_responders as
select sr.* from survey_responders sr
    join survey_responses sres
    on sres.survey_responder_id = sr.id
    where sr.survey_question_id = 1
    order by sr.id
```

Comment: where can`t see aliases.

Comment: got it to work. thanks. you guys are fast by the way.

Comment: @Mihai, why not? I am talking about table alias and not column alias. proof: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b808/2